# Markov Chains between X, Y, Z resulting into a degenerate random variable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have the following two Markov chains:
\begin{align}
X&\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z,\\
X&\rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y,
\end{align}
where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are random variables. I know based on these two Markov chains, I have the following equality:
\begin{equation}
\frac{p(y\lvert z)}{p(z\lvert y)} = \frac{p(y\lvert x)}{p(z\lvert x)}
\end{equation}
This establishes that the right-hand side does not depend on $x$. Does this imply that $X$ must necessarily be a singleton, i.e., a degenerate random variable with a support size of 1? If so, how can one prove this?

Comment: I do not understand your Markov Chain. What are the transition probabilities? Usually, the randomness _is in the transition_ between the deterministic states. You seem to have random states.

Comment: @WilliamM. Here the states can be considered deterministic. The mentioned markov chains simply imply that $p(x,y,z) = p(z\lvert y,x) p(y,x)=p(z\lvert y) p(y,x)$ and $p(x,y,z) = p(y\lvert z,x) p(z,x)=p(y\lvert z) p(z,x)$.